# How do I use getattr in conjunction with dict string formatting?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, class, data-structures

I have a data structure class and a table formatting class in which I want to format a file and output it.  I want the flexibility of creating formatters on the fly if the output needs to be changed.

```
class Row(object):
    __slots__ = ('date', 'item', 'expiration', 'price')
    def __init__(self, date, item, expiration, price=None):
        self.date = date
        self.item = item
        self.expiration = expiration
        self.price = ""

        if price:
            self.price = price

class Formatter(object):
    def row(self, rowdata):
        for item in rowdata:
            print('<obj date="{date}" item="{item}" exp="{expiration}" price="{price}" />\n').format(**item)


def print_table(objects, colnames, formatter):
    for obj in objects:
        rowdata = [str(getattr(obj, colname)) for colname in colnames]
        formatter.row(rowdata)
```

I'm calling this like so:

```
data = [Row("20180101", "Apples", "20180201", 1.50),
         Row("20180101", "Pears", "20180201", 1.25)]

formatter = Formatter()
print_table(data, ['date','item','expiration','price'], formatter)
```

What I'm expecting to see is:

`<obj date="20180101" item="Apples" exp="20180201" price="1.50" />
<obj date="20180101" item="Pears" exp="20180201" price="1.25" />`

I am currently getting the following error:
`TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str`

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to create a dict at any point in this code, yet you're trying to use `rowdata` as if its elements are dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
class Formatter(object):
    def row(self, rowdata):
        print('<obj date="{date}" item="{item}" exp="{expiration}" price="{price}" />\n'.format(**rowdata))


def print_table(objects, colnames, formatter):
    for obj in objects:
        rowdata = {colname: str(getattr(obj, colname)) for colname in colnames}
        formatter.row(rowdata)
```

You had 3 problems:

1. You treated rowdata as a list of items, while rowdata should be a single
   mapping between column name and data
2. You didn't create the mapping, only the results. `{colname: str(getattr(obj,  colname)) for colname in colnames}` creates a mapping between the name and the attribute. You may then pass it to `.format()` and it'll fully work.
3. You used `format()` on the `print()` function. You should use it on the string inside.

Answer (score 0):

`**item` is invalid because the `**` operator expects the named variable to be a dictionary (a *mapping*), and you have not provided that (item is a string). Thus, you need to convert `item` into a dictionary with the proper key/value pairs that you want in your format statement.